# UNIX Command to add image dimensions to filename?

Tags: image, unix, command-line, dimensions

I am sure this can be done somehow, but my limited knowledge with the UNIX command line needs a nudge here. What I want to do is the following:

1. There is a directory full of PNG files
2. Determine the image dimensions width and height of each image file
3. Rename the file foo.png to [width_value]x[height_value]_foo.png

Any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: does `image --help` (or other, like -h, -?) provide you with a clue on how to get info on a file? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `ls *.png`
do
   params=`get parameters from $i`
   mv $i params$i
done
```

left as an exercise for the OP is the program to get the information from the png file

Note that `sips` is the bsd command to get image information so:

```
height=`sips -g pixelHeight $i`
width=`sips -g pixelWidth $i`
mv $i $heightX$width$i
```